# Use Firebase Database in gradle

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, firebase-admin

I'm trying to make a gradle script to upload some data on build with firebase. But I'm getting a strange error from the Firebase Java Admin SDK:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials$CertCredential.<init>(FirebaseCredentials.java:273)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(FirebaseCredentials.java:156)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(FirebaseCredentials.java:130)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials$fromCertificate.call(Unknown Source)
    at eu.long1.jwnotes.gradleplugins.UploadTask.action(UploadTask.groovy:31)
```

The task this like this:

```
class UploadTask extends DefaultTask {

    String message = "Huray!"

    @TaskAction
    def action() {

        String a = "private-key"

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(a.getBytes("UTF-8"))))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://jwnotes.firebaseio.com/")
                .build()

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)


        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("alfa-gradle").setValue(message)
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error when I'm trying to apply to run the task.

**UPDATE**

this is my plugin gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'maven'
}

group 'eu.long1.jwnotes.gradleplugins'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.3.1'
    compile 'org.json:json:20160810'

}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

jar {
    into('lib') {
        from 'lib'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your runtime environment is picking up another version of `org.json:json` library that is not compatible with the Firebase SDK. You need to make sure it uses the correct version of the [json library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810). This generally requires inspecting the dependency tree, and putting an explicit exclude for some unnecessary dependencies.

**Update**

Following worked for me:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            mavenCentral()
            url uri('repo')
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.hkj', name: 'gradle-task',
                  version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.3.1'
    }
}

task greeting(type: net.hkj.UploadTask) {
}
```

I have the jar containing the compiled task in the repo directory. I put your task implementation into a src/main/groovy/net/hkj/UploadTask.groovy file, and compiled the output into the repo directory, before invoking the greeting task.

Comment: I thought on that but still I get the same error. I event tried to build the dependencies into the plugin jar.

Comment: Well, the method [definitely exists](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/20160810/JSONObject.java#L318) in the version 20160810. So this is an issue with Gradle not picking up the correct dependency. What if you drop the explicit dependency on `org.json:json`?

Comment: I went with the REST API in the end.